# How to create an add-in for VB editor?

Tags: vba, add-in

How to create VBA add-in for VB (not VB.NET) editor?

I have a piece of VBA code that I would like to have it available as add-in in VB editor window (menu -> Add-Ins) but I don't know how to create such thing, where should I put it.

Thanks!

Comment: `File - New project - AddIn`?

Comment: http://fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut03.htm some tips.

Comment: Yes, I found this also by searching but... in VS -> File -> New -> Project -> Other Languages -> Visual Basic... I see only Outlook2007 Add-in, Excel Add-in, etc, nothing about VB Editor. Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: The creator of MZ-Tools explaining how to create a VBE addin: http://www.mztools.com/articles/2012/MZ2012013.aspx

Comment: Side note: If you are not already using MZ-Tools for VBA you are missing out.  You might be re-inventing the wheel with your add-in...the functionality may already be in MZ-Tools.  I can't say enough good things about it.